# Set default value in custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, custom-controls

I am creating custom web control(textbox) which allows only integer data type in textbox.
On button submit event if there is no data in textbox, custom control should set TextBox1.Text=0, this is what i want. This is code which i wrote.

```
public class MasIntTextBox : TextBox
{
    private RequiredFieldValidator req;
    private RegularExpressionValidator regex;
    public string ValGrp { get; set; }
    public string IsRequired { get; set; }//give true/yes or false/no values only

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.CssClass = "inp-form";
        if (IsRequired == "true" || IsRequired == "yes")
        {
            req = new RequiredFieldValidator();
            req.ControlToValidate = this.ID;
            req.ErrorMessage = "Enter Numeric Value";
            req.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ValGrp))
                req.ValidationGroup = ValGrp;
            Controls.Add(req);
        }
        regex = new RegularExpressionValidator();
        regex.ControlToValidate = this.ID;
        regex.ErrorMessage = "Numeric Value Only";
        regex.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
        regex.ValidationExpression = "^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ValGrp))
            regex.ValidationGroup = ValGrp;
        Controls.Add(regex);
        //base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter w)
    {
        base.Render(w);
        if (IsRequired == "true" || IsRequired == "yes")
            req.RenderControl(w);
        regex.RenderControl(w);
    }
}
```

I checked few events or methods for this but they got fired after btnA_click event.
I am kind of newbie in this.
Any event or method i am missing? Any suggestion accepted.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the default value on TextBox.LostFocus event. This event fires immediately after focus is lost from the control (TextBox).

Comment: i want to add code in custom control class file, and if user don't focus on textbox then lostfocus/onblur will not fired..

Comment: Then add a default value to textbox.text  = "0" while initializing the user control. Empty the text box value to empty string ("") if it is "0" (default value) on it's GotFocus event. On LostFocus event, check the value and apply the default value if it's empty.

Comment: focus option is working but initializing it with 0 not working as codebehind its text property is "" instead of "0". i am writing if(string.IsnullorEmpty(this.text)){this.Text="0";}. Is it true...? writing this code in OnInit event is not effective as if i don't enter anything, click event is not getting .Text "0", its taking "" only...